# I need simple formula for data transformation according to this pattern

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm looking for an algorithm that has two input values and one output value and follows this pattern:

**Input_A: 10** (When INPUT_B is increased from 0 to 1 in very small steps, it should reach the value '1' 100/**10**=10 times.)

```
Input_B => Output  

0.025   => 0.25   
...  
0.05    => 0.50  
...  
0.075   => 0.75  
...  
0.1     => 1.00  
...  
0.125   => 0.25  
...  
0.15    => 0.50  
...  
0.175   => 0.75  
...  
0.2     => 1.00  
....
0.9     => 1.00
....
0.95    => 0.50
...
```

**Input_A: 20** (When INPUT_B is increased from 0 to 1 in very small steps, it should reach the value '1' 100/**20**=5 times.)

```
Input_B => Output  

0.025   => 0.50   
...  
0.05    => 1.00  
...  
0.075   => 0.50  
...  
0.1     => 1.00  
...  
0.125   => 0.50  
...  
0.15    => 1.00  
...  
0.175   => 0.50  
...  
0.2     => 1.00  
....
0.9     => 1.00
....
0.9125    => 0.25
...
0.925    => 0.50
...
0.95    => 1.00
...
```

I think I managed to create an algorithm that follows the first pattern. But I couldn't find one that follows both.

```
myAlgorithm(Input_A,Input_B) {
    return (Input_B && Input_B%0.1 == 0) ? 1 : Input_B%0.1 * Input_A;
}
```

Comment: You should at least tell us verbally what the logic is behind the two functions whose input and output you are showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need something like this:

```
 A10 = A * 10                   //0.175 * 10 = 1.75
 AInt = (Int)A10                //integer part = 1
 AFrac = A10 - AInt             //fractional part = 0.75
 Output  = AFrac? AFrac: 1.0 ;   //extra case of zero fractional part
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I was looking for! (Do you have suggestion for a better title of my question?)

Comment: Hmm.. Only abstract title like "I need simple formula for data transformation according to this pattern"